# Why storing form data in useState() hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I am somewhat familiar with React.

In react tutorials, I have seen people creating useState hooks to store form data and also making them controlled and started doing the same but recently I saw a video of coder creating a form without using any useState for storing the data?

This has left me stumped because I am not understanding why I need to store form data in useState hook now. For what type of situations, is it useful to use state or just simply take the form value?

Please help.

I have tried searching google, reading some blogs on useState hooks, how it is used where we want to re-render a component.

Like, If I am displaying some data, and want to change it on some event, then I will use useState hook so that it will re-render the display component, with the updated state.

But I am still not understanding its use case with forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a React form, you may want to do something on the screen as a user is typing using an `onChange` callback. You would need to store the user's input in state in order to properly deal with it in a `useEffect`. Just storing naked variables in components in React is terrible practice.

You generally only use destructured constants or derived conditional variables after hooks are called in a component in order to affect the display or to pass hook results as input to other hooks.

I would be interested to see the video or tutorial that showed you how to do a form "without state" in React because I'm not sure how that's possible - unless they were using a third-party library like `formik` which abstracts the `useState` away from you through it's own methods.

***ADDED EXAMPLE**

Consider this simple comparison of two forms, one with state and one without:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-sammet-imfzl5

**app.tsx**

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import FormWithState from "./FormWithState";
import FormWithoutState from "./FormWithoutState";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          border: "1px solid green",
          marginBottom: "1rem",
          padding: "1rem",
        }}
      >
        <div>
          This form with state notifies after 3 characters, and on submit.
        </div>
        <FormWithState />
      </div>
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid red", padding: "1rem" }}>
        <div>This form without state can't alert or useEffect</div>
        <FormWithoutState />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**FormWithState.tsx**

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function FormWithState() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(`You sent the message: ${message}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message.length >= 3) {
      alert("This message is longer than 3 characters. Wow!");
    }
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={onChange} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**FormWithoutState.tsx**

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function FormWithState() {
  let message = "";

  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    message = e.target.value;
  };

  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(`You sent the message: ${message}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message.length > 3) {
      alert("This message is longer than 3 characters. Wow!");
    }
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={onChange} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice how the green form can alert and useEffect as the user types / submits - while the red form cannot.

Both Forms:

[image]

This works (with state):
[image]

This does not work (without state):
[image]

I hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. Though, I would like know more about what you mean by this " You would need to store the user's input in state in order to properly deal with it in a useEffect".
Any use case with useEffect will do, not too take much of your time.

Also, here's the link to the video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4mjF4sPITE) chat_app. At 53:27, you can see the handleSubmit function.